# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GridFS'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

```
import pymongo
import gridfs
conn=pymongo.Connection()
db=conn.gridfs_testing
fs=gridfs.GridFS(db)
fs.list()
fs.put(open('/home/sairam_siripuram/Desktop/nba_data/01 - Intro.mp4','r'),filename='01 - Intro')
```

In the above code im trying to store mp4 file into mongodb using gridfs but it is throwing me the below error

Import Error:

```
Error:

 fs=gridfs.GridFS(db)
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GridFS'
 [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: I guess there is some problem with the `conn` object which is getting reflected in `fs` object , what does `conn.gridfs_testing` stands for  ?

Comment: Did you name one of your Python files `gridfs.py` and it got imported instead of the GridFS lib?